# Is it possible to assign the value for a variable by using other variable without changing their values in C++.?

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign the value for varC from varA and varB without changing the values of varA and varB.
But it seems that varA and varB is changing automatically along with varC when it is assigning the value for varC.
Here is My Code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main ()
{
    int varA = 10 ; // a = 10
    int varB = 10; // b = 10
    cout << "The exact value of varA is: " << varA <<'\n';
    cout << "The exact value of varB is: " << varB <<'\n';
    int varC = (++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ varA) += (varC = ++varB);
    cout << "After assigning the value for varC The value of varA is: " << varA <<'\n';
    cout << "After assigning the value for varC The value of varB is: " << varB <<'\n';

    cout << "The assigned value of varC is: " << varC <<'\n';
    cout << "The sum of varA, varB and varC is: " << varA + varB + varC << '\n';
    return 0;
```

Comment: `int varC = (++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ varA) += (varC = ++varB);`  No, don't do that.  Why.

Comment: This is madness

Comment: what are you doing? What  is this supposed to do     `int varC = (++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ varA) += (varC = ++varB);` You are incrementing you'r variables.

Comment: Is it for some obfuscation contest?

Comment: They're not changing automatically, they're changing because you're explicitly incrementing them.

Comment: @Silverfang yes I want to assign the value for varC by using this method.

Comment: by what method?  What is the value you want to assign  to c? How it is dependent on a and b ?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis yes exactly

Comment: Watch this: varC = varA + 10;     
TA DAAAA

Comment: @Silverfang the vaue 31 I want to assign for varC by using varA and varB

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann is there any non-madness way to assign value 31 for varC by using varA and varB ?

Comment: What exactly is the task? If it's about getting 31 as a function of 10 and 10 (why??) , then `c = 3*a + b/10;` would do.

Comment: varA + varB + varB + varA / varB = 31.

Comment: Right now, the question sounds like nonsense to me. Please put this in a reasonable context.

Comment: The task has been completed and for sure on Monday I will be getting the prize in university

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *pre-increment operator* `operator++` increments the value of the operand and then returns a reference to it.

`operator+=` likewise increments the left side by the value of the right side and then returns a reference to it.

In your expression your calling both multiple times. You're explicitely telling the compiler you want your values to be modified. If you just want to add numbers together without modifying the operands use `operator+`

Comment: @Саша Using `operator+` assigns values to `varC` without changing `varA` or `varB`. Thus, this answer fulfills your question. Another way would be to write `varC = 31;`. If `varA` has to be used, go with `varC = 31 + VarA - VarA;`, aka your question does not really make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

As can be seen here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

> Pre-increment and pre-decrement operators increments or decrements the
>   value of the object and returns a reference to the result.

The increment operators will be evaluated before the assignment of varC, therefore changing the values of varA and varB.

Comment: I know it but it will not help to assign 31 for varC by using varA and varB and without changing the value of varA and varB

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it unreadable then, so be it. Whatever is your value after doing that. you will have to reassign them or just code it. like you have already done
`varA=-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- (varA-=(varB=--varB));`

I am still wondering why are you doing this.

Comment: still not solved because it's changing the value of varA and varB because varA and varB has assigned values of 10. We cannot reassign it

Comment: Well it will change the values. Every time you write ++ or -- the values will get incremented or decremented by 1. If you don't want it and then change the code or you can use above method to cancel out the changes you have made in the same way.

Comment: I am doing this to protect my software from cracking.

Comment: @Саша This will not help slightly against reverse engineering. Also you realize that your code gets optimized anyways and will likely result in the same asm code?

Comment: @Silverfang Of course not because it is a part of the process for packing the software so nobody will be able to read the exact assembly code after packing by the new assembly encryption method

Comment: @Саша No. In reality, you *think* you protect your code while only making it unreadable.

Comment: Making it unreadable doesn't make it more secure. what you are doing is essentially a bad coding practice. Your code should always be easily readable.

Comment: @Aziuth it's mean they will crack and nothing can stop them?

Comment: @Silverfang I am making my (C++ Child script) so my code will be only readable by me and more easily then the real C++ code.

Comment: @Саша If you really need to encrypt things, start by visiting a beginners lecture on algebra. Then a intermediate one. Then you can proceed to proper encryption lectures. Or better, get a library that does all of that for you. I'm not even sure what you are trying to achieve here - what you want to protect is the content of a variable (like a stored password), not the code itself. And if the variable is plain in memory, it can be read, no matter how convoluted the code to create it is.

Comment: @Aziuth Ok, good suggestion )

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann But it will make it difficult in asm code as well, their will be extra calls for sum and it will make a headache for reverse engineer

Comment: @Саша Even then it won't be more than nuisance. For real obfuscation you have to take out much bigger guns, i.e load encrypted code at runtime, change PE headers etc. This is not a trivial endeavor and still people crack stuff like that regulary. But that is not even the point: When you build with optimiziations, i.e `-O2`, then all this will result in the same code. And if you dont build with optimizations you will have horribly slow code. Btw, before you have written this code, have you made sure that debug symbols were turned off? That would have been much more important...

Comment: its mean I have to jump in it later, thanks for the advice )